# Customize Django admin template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

i tried customizing navbar like this

**Base_site.html**

```
 {% block nav-global %}
 <img class = "brand_img" src = "{% static 'images/ic_launcher.png'%}" 
    width = "50" height = "50" alt = "logo">
 {%block branding%}    

  {% endblock %}
  <div class = "head">
    <h1 id = "name">Admin Dashboard</h1>
  </div>    
{% endblock %}
```

which looks like this

[image: admin page]

now i try to add header for login page inside {%block branding%}

[image: login page]

but if i add inside branding block it is displayed in navbar also and if i try to add both image and header in branding block image is displayed login page header.

how to add different titles for navbar and login page header?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be achieved pretty easily.

Inside your `templates` folder, you should have created an `admin` subfolder. Inside there, you should place the files `base_site.html` and `login.html`.

Contents of `base_site.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block branding %}
    <div class="head">
        <h1 id="name">Admin Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}
    <img class="brand_img" src="{% static 'images/ic_launcher.png'%}" width="50" height="50" alt="logo">
{% endblock %}
```

Contents of `login.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/login.html' %}

{% block branding %}
    <div class="head">
        <h1 id="name">Custom header text for LOGIN screen only</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is the correct project structure:

```
project/
    myapp/
    myapp2/
    project/
    templates/
        admin/
            base_site.html
            login.html
    manage.py
```

Please note the `extends` inside each html template you want to override. It's vital. For more info take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Comment: How do I place the logo before the `name` tag? I can see in the OP image the logo seems to be placed on the left of the page name. But can't get the effect. What would be the way around?

Comment: I think it should be as simple as swap the contents inside `{% block branding %}` and `{% block nav-global %}.` Or override `{% block branding %}` and put there both `h1` and `img` and just declare and leave empty the `{% block nav-global %}`.

Comment: The second trick does not work at all (the name value goes missing altogether). The first method worked. However, there is no space between the `name` and the **logo**, as if riding on the logo!!

Comment: If the problem is horizontal space, it can be solved via a CSS rule such as `#name {margin-left: 20px;}` or something similar according to your needs. But that is another question to be asked with a screenshot in order to visualize your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you need to adjust `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py` like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': .....,
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # <-- add this line here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                .....
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This is needed to tell your application where to look for these files.  This, in addition to @nik_m's solution above, did the trick for me ....