# Block content on admin template not overridden

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I extended django admin site according to [Customize Django admin template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533814/customize-django-admin-template) and [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block branding %}
    <div class="head">
        <h1 id="name">Admin Dashboard abc</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Custom Content</h2>
{% endblock %}


{% block nav-global %}
    <img class="brand_img" src="{% static 'images/ic_launcher.png'%}" width="50" height="50" alt="logo logo">
{% endblock %}
```

"block branding" & "block nav-global" is displaying correctly but "block content" is not making any change to admin site. The official doc says..

> If you want to use the admin layout, extend from admin/base_site.html:
>
> {% extends "admin/base_site.html" %} {% block content %} ... {%
>   endblock %}

And I did what the doc says but is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% block content %}` is populated by `index.html` which extends `base_site.html` therefore even if you do any changes in `base_site.html` it will be overriden by `index.html`'s `{% block content %}`. The possible solution is to delete everything in `index.html`'s block content and call `{{block.super}}` so if you do any changes in `base_site.html` they will be passed to `index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get `{% block content %}` to work extending the admin's template, you need to create an `index.html` file inside the folder admin, located in the template's DIR folder, which is the folder mentioned in Django's documentation, usually `templates/admin/index.html`, then in this file you can extend the `admin/index.html` file and replace the block content, for instance:

```html
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
{{ block.super }}
<p>this works</p>
{% endblock %}
```

To get the template's DIR, you can open up the settings.py file, it's an option like this

```py
TEMPLATES = [
        { 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'], }
]
```